# Force one way binding while assigning variable to another variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to assign a variable to another variable and try to do only one way binding. But when value is updated in view, it updates to original variable too. How do I stop this two way binding while assigning variable to another.

For example:

```
function personController ($scope) {
    var templateValue= "original value";

    $scope.myVal= templateValue;
}
```

In view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVal" />
```

Result:

When we type something in textbox, it updates value in `myVal` and `templateValue` too, i.e value in `templateValue` changes to whatever I just typed in the input box. Is there a way to assign variable to another variable doing only one way binding? I want two way binding between `$scope.myVal` and the input box but not between `templateValue` and input box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "force one-way binding" because of the weay JavaScript works.

In your example, updating `myVal` will not actually update `templateValue`.

```
function personController($scope) {
    var templateValue = "original value";
    $scope.myVal = templateValue;
}
```

If you have the following structure, then yes, changing `myVal.test` will update `templateValue.test` because they both reference the same object in memory.

```
function personController($scope) {
    var templateValue = { test: "original value" };
    $scope.myVal = templateValue;
}
```

if you want `myVal` and `templateValue` to reference different objects but have the same content, make a copy of the original object:

```
$scope.myVal = angular.copy(templateValue);
```

I also suggest familiarising yourself with [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value).